# Creating and populating an array in the simplest way

Tags: java, arrays

I am developing application..

```
    class Wheel {
    private int size;

    Wheel(int s) {
        size = s;
    }

    void spin() {
        System.out.print(size + " inch wheel spinning, ");
    }

}

public class Bicycle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wheel[] wa = { new Wheel(15), new Wheel(17) };
        for (Wheel w : wa)
            w.spin();
    }
}
```

But Please advise that how could we express `Wheel[] wa = { new Wheel(15), new Wheel(17) };` in more simpler terms.

Comment: Be sure to look into the Java Collections API. Collections are preferred over arrays, largely because Collections (Set, List, etc.) are easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a shorter expression for creating an array of wheels, what you have is a simple as it can get without additional methods.

You could create a factory method like so:

```
class Wheel {

    public static Wheel[] newWheels( int[] sizes ){
        Wheel[] result = new Wheel[sizes.length];
        for( int i=0; i < sizes.length; i++ )
           result[i] = new Wheel( sizes[i] );
        return result;
    }

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

Which would make your wheel creation statement:

```
Wheel[] wa = Wheel.newWheels( new int[]{ 15, 17 } );
```

Which isn't much simpler when you only have two wheels of predetermined size, but if you have more of them, or if the sizes aren't predetermined, this might be more readable.

Answer (score 6):

`Wheel[] wa = { new Wheel(15), new Wheel(17) };` is about as simple as you're going to get. What exactly are you expecting - do you have a problem that requires it to be simpler?

It isn't simpler, but if you want to make something that allows you to add more `Wheel`s, you'll need to break it out separately, such as...

```
Wheel[] wa = new Wheel[2];
wa[0] = new Wheel(15);
wa[1] = new Wheel(17);
```

or possibly...

```
int[] sizes = {15,17};
Wheel[] wa = new Wheel[sizes.length];
for (int i=0;i<sizes.length;i++){
    wa[i] = new Wheel(sizes[i]);
}
```

These are not simpler, but they are a lot nicer if you have a lot of `Wheel`s to create.

If you're only going to have 2 `Wheel`s though, your statement is pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
Wheel[] wa = { new Wheel(15), new Wheel(17) };
```

Its look like you are maintaining different number of wheel's collection.

so for each set you can create `java.util.Set<E>` (if collection contains no duplicate wheel)or use `java.util.List<E>` (duplicate allows)

and you can put into `array` or in map(`java.util.Map<K,V>`) . Map will be better option you can hold more control over specific `Set or List`.

```
    List<Wheel> wh1=new ArrayList<Wheel>(15);
    List<Wheel> wh2=new ArrayList<Wheel>(17);
    Map<String,List<Wheel>> wa=new HashMap<String,List<Wheel>>();
    wa.put("1stList", wh1);
    wa.put("2ndList", wh2);
```